# How to read csv with comma delimited that has columns with embedded commas in PySpark?

Tags: csv, pyspark

I am trying to read a CSV from AWS S3 bucket using pyspark. As my CSV has a column with embedded commas, it's not getting written to the dataframe correctly.

My Spark version is 2.4.4. Appreciate any help with this.

Below is the code.

```py
url= "<url of the file from AWS S3>"
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)
df = spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv(SparkFiles.get("drugsComTrain_raw.csv"), inferSchema=True, quote='\"', escape='\"',sep=",", timestampFormat="mm/dd/yy")
```

Output shows like this.

```
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------+-----------+
|            uniqueID|  drugName|           condition|              review|rating|     date|usefulCount|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------+-----------+
|              206461| Valsartan|Left Ventricular ...|"It has no side e...|     9|20-May-12|         27|
|               95260|Guanfacine|                ADHD|"My son is halfwa...|  null|     null|       null|
|We have tried man...|         8|           27-Apr-10|                 192|  null|     null|       null|

+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------+-----------+
```

Below is column with embedded commas.

```
df.select("review").show(1,truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|review                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|"It has no side effect, I take it in combination of Bystolic 5 Mg and Fish Oil"|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

```
df.select("uniqueID").show(5)

+--------------------+
|            uniqueID|
+--------------------+
|              206461|
|               95260|
|We have tried man...|
|               92703|
|The positive side...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

uniqueID should show only numbers.

Comment: it's more likely embedded newlines, try adding `multiLine=True` as an argument in `read.csv(...)`

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. That has solved the issue.

Comment: @jxc Please consider converting your comment to an answer and have ic2019 accept it.  That'll make it easier for others to benefit from your response.